# I can't start my phone unless I'm in safe mode. How to fix it?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, troubleshooting

So I have a problem. My phone is booting in download mode and I can't start it unless I use the <kbd>volume up</kbd>  + <kbd>home</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd>. I tried to wipe my phone, but it didn't  work and I lost my data for nothing.

When I'm able to start it, it's in safe mode and I can't remove the safe mode because when I try to, It's booting in download  mode.

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S4 running on android 5.0.1.

Comment: I also discovered that my volume down button is broken or maybe stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to flash on it new firmware via Odin, you can read instructions and download Odin and new firmware at http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/
It won't void your warranty.

Answer (score -1):

If the volume button is broken (as you write yours is), there is no other option than change it (or have it changed at the service center). It's an hardware problem.